# ALAssetGroup Name

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, alassetslibrary

Can you edit the ALAssetsGroupPropertyName property once it is created in IOS?  There appears to be only a getter for the property:

```
[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]
```

From the Photos App one can edit/change the name of the Album, but I can't find a way to change the album name in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to edit the ALAssetsGroupPropertyName for 3rd party applications using ALAssetsLibrary. I suggest you fill a radar for this feature extension.